# Create adjacency matrix for large id numbers

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, adjacency-matrix

I extracted some road data from `Openstreetmap` the relation between the crossroad are represented in a `node` and each `node` has an `id`, the extracted data has been converted to a data frame of shape `(50,2)` since I'm trying to implement on small size land

The data frame looks like this

```
    id_1        id_2
0     42807002  8219742091
1   8219742091  8219737904
2   8219737904    42807004
3     42839143  8219742075
4   8219742075    42807002
5     42807002    42839146
6     42839146    42839155
7     42839155    42839161
8     42839161    42839168
9     42839168  2875111804
10  2875111804    42839172
11    42839146  8219742083
12  8219742083  8219742024
13  8219742024    42845825
14    42839161  8219742048
15  8219742048  8219742063
16  8219742063    42862789
17    42839155  8219742066
18  8219742066  5427796641
19  5427796641  5427796639
20  5427796639  5427796630
```

and for further illustration, this is the graph relation between my nodes.

[image]

Each record shows that there is a link between id_1 and id_2.

I would like to create an `adjacency matrix` for this dataframe but I have a huge problem that the id names are so big (the largest value is 8219742092). I tried to use this code using `networkx`

```
G = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(df)
```

but as I expected it doesn't work since the `networkx` `adjacency` require nodes from 0 to 8219742092 and the number 8219742092 is so huge to create a dataset from it.

How can I make an adjacency matrix based on this data?

*Small note:* I can't rename the id.

Comment: In essence, your graph is a sparse graph, creating an adjacency matrix is never a good solution for sparse graphs, you must try to work with other solutions such as adjacency list or edge list, etc. Otherwise, you can create a dictionary mapping your node ids to small mapped ids and then work with your mapped ids. This is a workaround I am also working with in one of my problems. I hope this will help you too.

Comment: thank that's helped me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use this code using crosstab

```
cross = pd.crosstab(df['id_1'],df['id_2'])
adjacency_matrix=cross.values
```